# Chart responsive on p:layout

Tags: layout, charts

I'm using Primefaces 5.3 and got problem when place Chart responsive problem on p:layout

With p:layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx5Sp.png

Without p:layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmZVC.png

Please help me fix that  :(

Comment: Please share some code if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `responsive="true"` to your `p:chart` attribute.